# iPhone: how do I add the discolsure and delete icons to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to have a disclosure and delete icon on my UITableView how do I add them ?

I think the delete doesn't show all the time ? although I'm not sure about this, can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[complete tutorial for disclosure button](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43134/1954)

[complete tutorial for delete button](http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-using-table-views#)

Answer (score 0):

For the disclosure, you can set the accessoryType property in the desired cell.
For the delete button you should enable the "editing" property of the table, and set the "editing style" property of the cell.
You should also use the "editing" property of the table to switch between edit mode and regular.